# Is there a non-deterministic delay between writing an OID and creating a reference to the target OID, especially when done from separate processes?

Tags: libgit2

I have two separate processes writing to the same git repository. One is responsible for creating the commit object, and one is supposed to wait until the object is found using git_object_lookup_prefix before moving on to actually create the reference.

It seems that occasionally I have some non-determinism, in that the git object is found, I try to write the reference, and the create_reference call fails reporting that the target oid isn't found in the repository.

I even tried to unload the repository, wait 5 seconds, reload the repository and try to create the reference again, but it still failed.

Ideas? Wait longer? Something else?

Comment: What's the error message that you're getting?  I assume it's "target OID for the reference doesn't exist on the repository"...

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: I'm surprised...  we should invalidate caches here.  You mentioned `git_object_lookup_prefix` - what's the length of the prefix you're passing? Is it a full OID or abbreviated?  Network filesystem?

I fear that StackOverflow may not be the best here - feel free to drop by slack or irc, or our issues.  This doesn't seem like an obvious usage error...

Comment: It's a full OID. Repo is stored in NFS, so I imagine that could introduce some issues. I'm going to add some additional delays in a loop for a bit to potentially see if there's some amount of time that will fix the issue. I can jump into slack if it continues. I know a non-deterministic error is a pain to debug.

Comment: Yeah, NFS frequently caches stat data, I'd expect our access(2) check is failing here by looking in the cache.  My NFS experience is years out of date, though, so I don't gave great advice.  Are you able to tweak the attributes cache on the client? https://serverfault.com/questions/278349/nfs-detecting-remotely-created-files-programmatically